# Error when starting mariadb - no such process

Tags: mysql, wordpress, laravel, mariadb, valet

I installed mariadb via homebrew to set up a wordpress enviroment. It is meant to work with laravel valet. I am currently using using the zsh shell.

I installed it without a problem (10.3.12), but when I run mysql.server start I get the following error:

```
mysql.server start
Starting MariaDB
.190206 11:26:18 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/chriss-mbp.lan.err'.
190206 11:26:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server: line 260: kill: (55179) - No such process
 ERROR!
```

Can anybody help me narrow down why I'm getting this error? I'm new to terminal and mariadb, so I'm hoping it's just a silly error that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: How is this related to Laravel, Wordpress or Valet? Please do not use irrelevant tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brew has its own service manager included. Via `brew services list` you get all installed services listed. MariaDB should be there.

To start it call `brew services start mariadb`.

Comment: brew info mariadb lists both options: both `mysql.server start` and `brew services start mariadb`. To start as a service is not related to an error when manually starting, in fact: most likely starting the service will have the same effect... mariadb not starting.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the offending line in the startup script, this error indicates:

1. the startup script timed out waiting for the server to come up, and
2. the server process isn't running.

The command name `kill` is a little misleading; it's most commonly used to kill a process, but it can also be used to send an arbitrary signal, or even (with `-0`) just to [check whether it would be possible to send a signal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169899/17155), which is what's happening here.

To find out *why* the server didn't come up, you need to check the error log, which on a macOS / Homebrew installation of MySQL or MariaDB is going to be in:

```
/usr/local/var/mysql/<hostname>.err
```

If you `tail` that file, you should see the reason for the failure, e.g.

```
2019-11-01 11:29:14 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port.
  Got error: 48: Address already in use
2019-11-01 11:29:14 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server
  running on port: 3306 ?
2019-11-01 11:29:14 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

(In my case I had another instance of MariaDB running in a Docker container and squatting on port 3306.)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo tail -f /usr/local/var/mysql/[your computer host name].err`

```
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.42-84.2 started; log sequence number 149299467171
2021-01-22 13:16:17 123145364480000 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [ERROR] Bad magic header in tc log
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [ERROR] Crash recovery failed. Either correct the problem (if it's, for example, out of memory error) and restart, or delete tc log and start mysqld with --tc-heuristic-recover={commit|rollback}
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2021-01-22 13:16:17 4581617088 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I was running MariaDB 10.1 locally and boot up a MariaDB 10.5, somehow my `/usr/local/var/mysql/tc.log` was affected and I have to rename it to boot my local 10.1 again.

```
sudo mv /usr/local/var/mysql/tc.log  /usr/local/var/mysql/tc.log_ 
sudo mysql.server start

Starting MariaDB
.210122 14:30:56 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/[your computer host name].err'.
210122 14:30:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
 SUCCESS!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to seek the error inside the log file `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`.
My was configured non-existing , better said not yet imported/configured time-zone.